# returning a float value when writing a function in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I am writing a simple function in c that will return the middle of 2 float values.

My function looks like this:

```
float mid(float a, float b) {
      return (a + b)*0.5; 
}
```

The problem is that this function will always produce 0.000000. I am checking this by using:

```
printf("%f", mid(2,5))
```

this will print 0.000000.

However, if i just do:

```
printf("%f", (2+5)*0.5)
```

this will print 3.5, which is correct.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: can you post the complete code. was the function defined in the same CU?

Comment: Update your question to show us a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem. Read this: http://sscce.org/. Your function looks ok. I have a hunch about what the problem might be, but it will take a self-contained program to make it clear.

Comment: Works fine for my! I run the program and it printed 3.5. Mayby some more code would help. Also try this: printf("%f", mid(2.0, 5.0));

Comment: And if you got any warnings when compiling your code, include those in the question as well.

Answer (score 10):

The function is fine. For example, this little snippet outputs correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float mid(float a, float b);     //declaration here

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", mid(2,5));
    return 0;
}
float mid(float a, float b) {
      return (a + b)*0.5;
}
```

The probable problem you have is, you didn't add the declaration of `mid()` like I did, and the compiler thought it returns implicit `int`, which causes the problem.

Comment: +1 You can *likely* add "... and ignored the warning about "implicit declaration of function `mid` returns `int`" or similar language to that list of symptoms.

Comment: @Will: In modern C (ISO C99 and later), return values do not default to `int`.

Comment: A draft of the C99 standard is [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). The foreword mentions the removal of the implicit `int` rule. A draft of the 2011 standard is [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: @Will you don't need a prototype if you declare the function before main or its first use

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: A function definition provides a declaration, which *is* a prototype (assuming it specifies the parameter type(s)).

Answer (score 2):

This should work! But I suggest you to pass explicitly double values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
float mid(float a, float b);

int main() {

    printf("%f", mid(2.0, 5.0));

    return(0);

}

float mid(float a, float b) {
      return (a + b)*0.5; 
}
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, you're not passing floats either. You're passing doubles.

Comment: @sharth Agree, but any reasonable competent will convert the `2.0, 5.0` _at compile time_ to `2.0f, 5.0f`.  Would not expect any generated code difference had the code been written `mid(2.0f, 5.0f)`.  Yes, the result of `mid()` may be converted to `double`, passed to `printf()`, which then converts to `float` for printing purposes.  Some compilers do examine constant formats and could skip the `mid()` result --> `double` --> `print float` and simple do `mid()` result --> `print float`.

Comment: @chux: The original answer suggested that passing the variables as floats was _better_. I was pointing out that Rizier was not actually following their own advice. That being said, I mostly agree. I'd expect any reasonable compiler to convert this entire code to: `printf("%f", 3.5f);`

Comment: @sharth An aside: In embedded world, the compiler examines the constant format so only the needed conversions are implemented in code rather than the whole `printf()`.  I wonder if this would simplify into `fputs("3.500000", stdout);`  Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Why do you suggest passing doubles to a function that takes floats?

Comment: @sharth I wouldn't expect any compiler to do that

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Both gcc and clang will optimize out the call to `mid` in the above code. They both call `printf` with a constant `3.5`. https://gist.github.com/sharth/691452010c1e935bf384